# How to Know which button clicked on Rg.Plugins.Popup

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using a Rg.Plugins.Popup PCL in Xamarin form and opening popup after button click. I want to know the process of which i can understand which button is clicked on the popup so  i can implement next part of code according to the selection on Popup.

```
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
         x:Class="ATSDriver.PopupDemo">
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#ffffff" >
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Padding="2">
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                <Label Text="Order Item Picture " TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center" ></Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <Button Text="Next Picture" x:Name="btnClose" Clicked="btnClose_Clicked" StyleClass="ButtonLightBlack"></Button>
            <Button Text="Complete Picture" x:Name="btnComplete" Clicked="btnClose_Clicked" StyleClass="ButtonLightBlack"></Button>
        </StackLayout>   
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**code of click event**

```
private async void btnClose_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PopPopupAsync();
    }
```

**calling the popup**
Below code, I am using for the camera after taking the first picture i will open the above popup. If the user clicked on Next Picture then user an take next picture. If the user clicks on Complete picture i will close the camera and stop process. Currently i am using `DisplayAlert` but i want to use above popup.

```
async void bttnDelivery_Clicked1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var testPopup = new PopupDemo();
            await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(testPopup); 
// var action2 = await DisplayAlert("Do you want to continue take pictures?", "", "Complete Pictures", "Next Picture");                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Simply I want to change my below code part of Display Alert to use this Popup

```
 var action2 = await DisplayAlert("Do you want to continue take pictures?", "", "Complete Pictures", "Next Picture");
                    if (action2 == false)
                    {
                        goto Pic;
                    }
                    if (action2 == true)
                    {
}
```

Hope my questions is clear to you. Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

I'd struggled with such a thing too in the past and I made up a kind of 'pattern' to solve my problem like is shown bellow. The code is just a sample applied to your scenario, but I think you'll get the main idea.
I'm not sure it's the best way to do it in a MVVM enviroinment, but it's working very well to me.

**Recipe:**

- Create a `TaskCompletionSource` of the type you wanna deal (bool, enum, some more complex class);
- Send the task to the page outside your domain context, but be sure this outside context handle the possible results
- Await (or be prepared) to receive a answer about the sended task
- Handle the results, if the task is executed as expected

In your specific case, here's the code:

**Create an enum (Don't mind, it's just my OCD)**

```
public Enum EnumAction
{
    NextPicture,
    CompletePicture
}
```

**Expect for one `TaskCompletionSource` at your page's constructor**

```
public partial class PopupDemo : Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage
{
    private TaskCompletionSource<EnumAction> task;

    public PopupDemo(TaskCompletionSource<EnumAction> taskCompletion)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        task = taskCompletion;
    }
}
```

**Handle your events (or commands) setting the task result**

```
private async void btnClose_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Navigation.PopPopupAsync();
    task?.SetResult(EnumAction.NextPicture)
}

private async void btnComplete_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Navigation.PopPopupAsync();
    task?.SetResult(EnumAction.CompletePicture)
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();

    if(task != null)
        if(!task.Task.IsCanceled && !task.Task.IsFaulted && !task.Task.IsCompleted)
            task.SetCanceled();
}
```

**Receive the result on your domain context when it's set by the outside page**

```
async void bttnDelivery_Clicked1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var taskResult = new TaskCompletionSource<EnumAction>();
        taskResult.ContinueWith(result => 
            {
                if(result.IsCompleted)
                {
                    switch (result.Result)
                    {
                        case EnumAction.NextPicture:
                            break; // Make your magic here
                        case EnumAction.CompletePicture:
                            break; // Make your magic here
                        default:
                            break; // Make your magic here
                    }
                }
            });
        var testPopup = new PopupDemo(taskResult);
        await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(testPopup); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

If you get a better way to do such a thing, please share with us.

I hope it help you (sorry for any english mistake).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I have understand correctly your question, but I think you can use two separated method

```
   <Button Text="Next Picture" x:Name="btnClose" Clicked="btnClose_Clicked" StyleClass="ButtonLightBlack"></Button>
   <Button Text="Complete Picture" x:Name="btnComplete" Clicked="btnCompleted_Clicked" StyleClass="ButtonLightBlack"></Button>
```

Change `btnClose_Clicked` to `btnCompleted_Clicked`

then you can use MessagingCenter...

your popup send MessagingCenter. Your Page Subscribe to these MessagingCenter.

in btnCloseClicked you can Send a MessagingCenter with "Next"; in btnCompletedClicked you can send a MessagingCenter with "Completed"

Comment: i have one issue that is when user click next picture or complete picture i call it on same part where the user take one picture and i will popup this popup to take next or complete picture.

Comment: i want to use this popup instead of this   `var action2 = await DisplayAlert("Do you want to continue take pictures?", "", "Complete Pictures", "Next Picture");`

Comment: I have not understand the problem... Can you press Next or Complete?

Comment: i have added description in  calling the popup part in my question

Comment: added a comment to my answer @A.Goutam

Comment: i want to open the popup when after taking the first picture by the user. If user click the Next Picture on the popup user can take next picture by the camera if user clicked on complete Picture then i will stop to take picture by the camera curren i am using this code

Comment: `var action2 = await DisplayAlert("Do you want to continue take pictures?", "", "Complete Pictures", "Next Picture");
                    if (action2 == false)
                    {
                        goto Pic;
                    }
                    if (action2 == true)
                    {  // do something 
}`

Comment: You can't "wait" the answer like you do with DisplayAlert... Popup the "popup" and use MessagingCenter to send a message from popup to calling page.

Comment: I've used a `TaskCompletionSource` to do something like this. When I create the popup, I send a `TaskCompletionSource` as constructor parameter and when the action is taken inside the popup, I return the result of it. Is that what you want, @A.Goutam?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza yes i can use same as you say